# Quickly Save multiple images

Tags: image

I am going to upload a file to be rendered on RenderST. My .blend has a video file in it so I am not able to use "auto pack data" since it does not pack video files.

The problem is I have 100+ images associated with my .blend file. These are pulled from many different files from our work servers and I have no idea where the original files are all located. So I need to save out these images one by one from blender to put in their own folder to upload to RenderSt.

Is there a quicker way of doing this? maybe a python script?

EDIT:

Added pic to make it a little clearer

[image]

Comment: First, Blender *can* pack videos.  I just verified it.  But if something is preventing you, can you temporarily remove the video, pack, then unpack the image files to your desktop, then add the video file back later?

Comment: That is a good idea, however how do I unpack the images to desktop?  I see something that says "Unpack all files" but its grayed out.

Comment: Uncheck the "Automatically pack into Blend" check box then it should allow you to do it

Comment: ahhhh, you're awesome! that did the trick. Thank you very much. I know you said you just verified that videos can be packed but everywhere I look it says that videos DON'T get packed. I wonder why everywhere says that? either way you are the man! I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, so glad it worked for you.  I don't know why, maybe there's a filesize limitation.  I used a 110MB video to verify, unpacked it to another directory, and then played it and it worked fine.

Comment: I have never been able to pack a video. What kind of asset was it? A texture or a Movie clip from the tracker or a VSE strip?

Comment: @3pointedit - a .mov in the VSE.  That was the quickest way of testing.

Comment: How did you determine that the file was packed and not just referencing the external file?

Comment: Sorry @3pointedit I didn't see your last comment.  If you could, please use the @ symbol so SE tells me.  Just tried it again with a 668MB video w/sound.  Packed the video, saved blend, closed Blender. The blend file was 668MB.  I then deleted the actual referenced video from it's file location.  Reopened Blender, unpacked the video to a different file location and played the video with Windows Media Player... works perfectly.  2.78c  - Can you try it and see if it works?

Comment: @bertmoog Ok some tests, using a 10mb mp4 with audio. Packed audio strip via strip properties - worked (10mb increase) // Packed strip via File>External Data - worked "1 file packed" (10mb increase) // Delete audio strip only, leave video strip - can't pack via strip properties // Delete audio strip only, leave video strip // Packed strip via File>External Data -Doesn't Work but says "1 file packed" (no increase in blend file size)

Comment: @bertmoog seems like the whole .mp4 is being packed when the audio gets packed, so it's an unintended side effect? I couldn't pack video alone. Probably wouldn't work for Movie Textures either. Haven't tried it with larger files yet, but its a fun cheat ;-)

Comment: @3pointedit - Hmmm.  Interesting, I just tried that and verified what you're saying.  Weird.  I can't understand why Blender wouldn't just pack whatever dependencies you have associated.  Why make a distinction between video only and video with audio?

Comment: Traditionally Blender has never packed video. I expect that is a legacy decision from when video files where HUGE and internet speed was sloooow.

Comment: @bertmoog also note that what you pack may not be accessible as a video file if the pointer is only for sound. Fine if you unpack to folder but no good for distributed renders

Comment: @3pointedit - I guess you could always just use video files with a muted audio track if packing was absolutely necessary.

Answer (score -3):

By the time you get the script completed and run it, you may have your files loaded.  Loading them to your computer in a folder with subfolders based on file sizes, then updloading them is usually best. Load from smallest image sizes to largest folder.

Comment: This isnt the problem. I need to take the files out of blender and download them to my desktop. Normally you go to uv/image editor and then choose your picture and then save as.. I dont want to do this 100+ times. Hoping someone has a script for this.